# Are module categories over a semisimple category semisimple?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, \oplus, I, a, r, l)$ be an abelian semisimple monoidal category, then are all module categories over $\mathcal{C}$ necessarily semisimple?

I can convince myself that they need to be additive and have indecomposable objects, but I cannot see semisimplicity.

Thanks,

Comment: Answered on MSE (after it was posted here) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649393/are-module-categories-over-a-semisimple-category-semisimple